# Почему дублируется обработчик событий?

Tags: javascript, события, javascript-events

Есть сайт на котором установлена LightGallery (фотогалерея, https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/docs/settings/). При клике на превью фото открывается два слайдера. Это видно при перелистывании и при закрытии слайдера. Все дело в том что на превью весит два обработчика которые открывают слайдер. Я не нашел где вешается второй обработчик. Задача - оставить только один обработчик. В процессе поиска я заметил что на некоторых страницах слайдер работает как надо, открывается только один раз. Если обновить страницу на котором слайдер дублируется, то проблема исчезает. То есть, если зайти по прямой ссылке на страницу галереи проблема не воспроизводится (https://neopolisdom.nabiullin.com/zagorodnye-doma/object_0160/), но если перейти из общего каталога (https://neopolisdom.nabiullin.com/zagorodnye-doma), то она тут как тут.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно Вам только посоветовать искать дальше, т.к. предоставленной Вами информации явно не хватает для однозначного определения причины такого поведения. Сравните страницы/поведение/создание страниц при прямых ссылках и при переходе из общего каталога.

Comment: Не так все и сложно. Откройте консоль и найдите метод catalogSlider в main.js, в нем вызывается addEventListener. Если поставить breakpoint и выполнить кейс с переходом, то видно что addEvent вызывается два раза. Открываем вкладку network, там видим что при переходе догружается код. Идем в самый низ кода и видим, что зачем-то два раза вызывается catalogSlider() при условии что он typeof catalogSlider !== 'undefined'. Дальше смотрите свой код, почему вы так сделали.

Comment: Да, в этом и была проблема. Код не я писал, поэтому кое как нашел его. Спасибо за помощь!